# Scanner exception while reading different types of variables

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have such a file:

```
3
0.1
0.4
1
```

And this is how I try to read it:

```
InputStream s = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/file.txt");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);
//Scanner scanner = new Scanner(path); **EDITED**
System.out.println(scanner.nextInt());
System.out.println(scanner.nextDouble());
System.out.println(scanner.nextDouble());
System.out.println(scanner.nextInt());
```

InputMismatchException is thrown in third line of my code. I know I can use readLine() and parse it to int or double, but it would not work, if my file would look like:

```
3 0.1
0.4
1
```

In this situation, the same exception is thrown in the same place.

Comment: What is `path`?

Comment: I wrote "path" to shorten my code, but actually I have "InputStream s = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/file.txt");" and then I have "Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your description it looks like a locale problem. As stated by [`Scanner` docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

> An instance of this class is capable of scanning numbers in the standard formats as well as in the formats of the scanner's locale. A scanner's initial locale is the value returned by the [`Locale.getDefault()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getDefault()) method; it may be changed via the [`useLocale(java.util.Locale)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useLocale(java.util.Locale)) method. The [`reset()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#reset()) method will reset the value of the scanner's locale to the initial locale regardless of whether it was previously changed.

I presume your default locale is Polish locale, which decimal separator is a comma. You might want to change your input files to use your locale decimal separator or use a locale which decimal separator is a dot. For example, you could add the following line after the `Scanner` initialization:

```
scanner.useLocale(Locale.US);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - it worked! I changed dots in my file to commas. Changing locale in scanner also does the job.

Looks like Windows' line separator ("\r\n" instead of "\n") has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Glad it helped. Windows/Unix separator is irrelevant in this case indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set the path using a `File` or `InputStream` source.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("path/filename.ext"));

System.out.println(scanner.nextInt());
System.out.println(scanner.nextDouble());
System.out.println(scanner.nextDouble());
System.out.println(scanner.nextInt());
```

Comment: I wrote "path" to shorten my code, but actually I have "InputStream s = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/file.txt");" and then I have "Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);"

Comment: If you have done that then you code should definitely run :)

Comment: @WojciechKazior Are u sure there aren't any non printable characters in your text file? Else can u retry creating the same input file using `vi` editor or something...???

Comment: Maybe you are right, the problem could be Windows' line separator ("\r\n"), I will check it. Here you can look at my project: http://i.imgur.com/GwarAio.png

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to reproduce this error. Consider the following example:

```
$ cat -A file
3$
0.1$
0.4$
1$

$ cat -A file2
5 0.1$
0.4$
1$

$ cat Test.java

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test
{
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    InputStream s = Test.class.getResourceAsStream(args[0]);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);
    System.out.println(scanner.nextInt());
    System.out.println(scanner.nextDouble());
    System.out.println(scanner.nextDouble());
    System.out.println(scanner.nextInt());

  }
}

$ javac Test.java 

$ java Test file
3
0.1
0.4
1

$ java Test file2
5
0.1
0.4
1
```

The code you posted should work as expected.

Comment: Same. I can't see the issue. Maybe an out-of-date compile?

Comment: I wrote "path" to shorten my code, but actually I have "InputStream s = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/file.txt");" and then I have "Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);"

Comment: @WojciechKazior: Even with your updated sample I can't reproduce it. The output is exactly the same.

Comment: Here you can look at my project: http://i.imgur.com/GwarAio.png
Maybe the problem is Windows' line separator?

Comment: @WojciechKazior: It could be... That's why I used `cat -A` that displays the hidden characters. Check your files too to see if there is anything weird in there.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some advices, I found out that the problem was Windows' line separator. Instead of "\n" Windows prints "\r\n" which is not consumable by Scanner. I checked my file in Git Bash:

```
$ cat -A file.txt
3^M$
0.1^M$
0.4^M$
1
```

It should look:

```
$ cat -A file.txt
3$
0.1$
0.4$
1
```

**EDIT:**

It turned out that line separator has nothing to do with it. User "acm" noticed that it is a locale problem - in Poland default decimal separator is comma. Thanks a lot!